# how to get the graphs as shown on the apache server-status page

Tags: apache-2.2

I have got the server-status page to work and it returns in plain html. But the apache status-page as lot of useful graphs and scoreboards that are not included in the plain html, so the question is what do i do to get those graphs?

Answer (score 0):

They use the `mod_lua` module to execute a custom `Lua` script available via `Github` [here](https://github.com/Humbedooh/server-status).

*Note*: You will need to enable the `mod_lua` module in Apache as well as install some `Lua` runtime environment (details available [here](https://www.lua.org/download.html))